# Does $\mathsf{Q}$ have any interesting provably recursive functions?

Tags: lo.logic, computational-complexity, model-theory, computability-theory, proof-theory

*This question was [asked and bountied](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3802162/can-all-mathsfq-provably-recursive-functions-be-frequently-termlike) at MSE without success.*

For an appropriate theory $T$, say that an **$n$-ary $T$-provably recursive function** is a $\Sigma_1$ formula $\varphi$ with $n+1$ free variables which $T$ proves defines a total function. Terms and "near-terms" (e.g. "$\Delta_1$-piecewise combinations" of terms) are of course always $T$-provably recursive, but in general these account for only a miniscule fragment of the $T$-provably recursive functions (consider exponentiation in $\mathsf{PA}$).

I'm interested in whether [$\mathsf{Q}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic) has any such "surprising" provably recursive functions:

> Is there any $n$-ary $\mathsf{Q}$-provably recursive function $\varphi(\overline{x},y)$ such that for every $\{+,\times\}$-term $t(\overline{x},\overline{z})$ we have $$\mathsf{Q}\vdash\forall \overline{z} \exists a\forall \overline{x}[\bigwedge_{1\le i\le n}x_i>a\implies \neg\varphi(\overline{x},t(\overline{x}, \overline{z}))]?$$

Intuitively, I'm asking whether there is a $\mathsf{Q}$-provably recursive function which is $\mathsf{Q}$-provably eventually different from every term. Note that "eventually different" here is used in the sense of "different on all inputs with each coordinate sufficiently large." In particular, a function like $$\varphi(x_1,x_2,y)\equiv (y=0\wedge x_1=x_2)\vee(y=1\wedge x_1\not=x_2)$$ is **not** an example; while there is no specific term to which it is eventually equal, both $0$ and $1$ are terms to which it is not eventually not equal. (I'm like $80\%$ sure I got that right.)

Comment: The easiest candidates for $\phi$ are formulas defining numbers near $x/2$ or $\sqrt{x}$, but then we can show that any formula like $\forall x \exists! y, \phi(x,y)$ fails in some non-standard models of $Q$. So presumably the question is how to go more generally from a purported function $\phi$ to a model where the above sentence fails.

Comment: @MattF. Yes, exactly - but it's not clear to me how to do that.

Comment: It might suffice to consider the model of $Q$ consisting of all elements of $\mathbb{Z}[t]$ whose non-constant coefficients are non-negative and which have at least one positive coefficient. Perhaps for any purported $\phi$ eventually always different from any term, it can be shown that $\forall x \exists! y, \phi(x,y)$ fails in this model, using $x=t$.

Comment: The predecessor function is provably total in $Q$, and it is eventually different from each term in the standard model, but under its most natural definition, $Q$ does not prove the formula you want. I’m not sure if it can be reformulated so that $Q$ *does* prove the formula. In general, it’s extremely difficult for $Q$ to prove any two functions to be eventually different, because of black-hole models of $Q$ such as $\mathbb N\cup\{\infty\}$ [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/194502).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek That's a good point - it would probably be better to add monus to the language and go a bit beyond $\mathsf{Q}$.

Comment: Actually, the $\mathbb N\cup\{\infty\}$ model outright shows that the answer is NO, and you don’t even need $+$ and $\times$ (just constant terms): let $z$ be such that $\mathbb N\cup\{\infty\}\models\varphi(\vec\infty,z)$; then $\mathbb N\cup\{\infty\}\models\forall a\,\exists\vec x\,\bigl(\bigwedge_ix_i>a\land\varphi(\vec x,z)\bigr)$, namely $\vec x=\vec\infty$.